# Ubuntu 16.04 Eclipse CPP - error adding symbols: Bad value

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, opencv, gcc

I took my cpp app that was working on VS in windows env and tried to compile it in linux using eclipse.
i followed the steps described in 
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation

and i keep getting the following error message:

> 17:16:29 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project
>   deskLinux **** make all  Building target: libdeskLinux Invoking: GCC
>   C++ Linker g++ -L/usr/local/lib
>   -L"/home/ben/work/DeskLinux/deskLinux:/" -shared -o "libdeskLinux"  ./src/deskLinux.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lgflag -lglog
>   -lceres -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d  -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib  -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann /usr/bin/ld: ./src/deskLinux.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can
>   not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   ./src/deskLinux.o: error adding symbols: Bad value makefile:45: recipe
>   for target 'libdeskLinux' failed collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status make: *** [libdeskLinux] Error 1
>
> 17:16:29 Build Finished (took 112ms)

any ideas?

Comment: Dil you try the advice in the error message? Include `-fPIC` and recompile.

Comment: sort of, tried it in a few places but i guess i didnt find the right conf to add this flag